# Append checkbox value in codeigniter activerecord

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am just new in this using javascript and I am having a hard time in appending a value from a checkbox to a table cell with a inputbox inside. When I check one of the checkbox(fee_type) the table is populated by all the fee types from the data base and plus the the amount table must be populated in the amount and penalty table(please see attached image of the actual view form)... please help me with this problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

[The Actual View Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddIUY.jpg)

--Form View--

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Grade Level</label>
 <select  id="class_id" name="class_id" class="form-control" >
  <option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>
    <?php foreach ($classlist as $class) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $class['id'] ?>" 
       <?php if (set_value('class_id') == $class['id']) {
            echo "selected =selected";
       }
       ?>><?php echo $class['class'] ?></option>
       <?php
       $count++;
       }
       ?>
       </select>
       <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('class_id'); ?></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fee Group Name</label>
        <select autofocus="" id="fee_groups_id" name="fee_groups_id" class="form-control" >
            <option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>  
        </select><span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fee_groups_id'); ?></span>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>amount</label>
    <input id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('amount'); ?>" />
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('amount'); ?></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Penalty</label>
    <input id="penalty" name="penalty" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('penalty'); ?></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fee type</label>

    <?php foreach ($feetypeList as $feetype) { ?>
        <div class="checkbox" >
            <label style="display: inline-block; max-height: 25px; list-style: none; float: left; padding-top: 5px; width: 130px; margin-right: 40px;">
            <input id="chkAdd" type="checkbox" name="feetype_id" value="<?php echo $feetype['id'] ?>" <?php echo set_checkbox('feetype', $feetype['id']); ?> ><?php echo $feetype['type'] ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
         <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('feetype_id'); ?></span>
</div>
```

--Javascript--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#chkAdd", function () {
        var lenght_div = $('#TextBoxContainer .app').length;
        var div = GetDynamicTextBox(lenght_div);
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#btnGet", function () {
        var values = "";
        $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
            values += $(this).val() + "\n";
        });
    });
});
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    var row = "";
    $('#chkAdd:checked').each(function(){
    row += '<tr class="tableGroup">';
<?php foreach ($feetypeList as $feetype) { ?>
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input class="form-control" name="feetype_id" value="<?php echo set_value('feetype_id', $feetype['type']); ?>"/></td>';
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input class="form-control" name="startDate"  value="<?php echo set_value('startDate', $feetype['start_date']); ?>"/></td>';
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input class="form-control" name="endDate" value="<?php echo set_value('startDate', $feetype['end_date']); ?>"/></td>';
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input id="amountCell" name="amountCell" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"/></td>';
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input id="penaltyCell" name="penaltyCell" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"/></td>';
    row += '</tr>';

<?php
$count++;
}
?>    
    });
    row = row.substring();
    $(".tableGroup").val(row);
    return row;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".feemaster_form").submit(function (e)
    {
        $("#TextBoxContainer").html("");
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: formURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: postData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        if (data.st === 1) {
                            $.each(data.msg, function (key, value) {
                                $('.' + key + "_error").html(value);
                            });
                        } else {
                            var response = data.msg;
                            if (response && response.length > 0) {
                                for (i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) {
                                    var feetype_id = response[i].feetype_id;
                                    var row_id = response[i].id;
                                    appendRow(feetype_id, row_id);
                                }
                            } else {
                                appendRow(0, 0, 0);
                            }

                            $('#chkAdd');

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                    }
                });

        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
function appendRow() {
    var value = $('#TextBoxContainer .app').length;    
    var row = "";
   row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input class="form-control" name="feetype_id" value="<?php echo set_value('feetype_id', $feetype['type']); ?>"/></td>';
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input class="form-control" name="startDate"  value="<?php echo set_value('startDate', $feetype['start_date']); ?>"/></td>';
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input class="form-control" name="endDate" value="<?php echo set_value('startDate', $feetype['end_date']); ?>"/></td>';
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input id="amountCell" name="amountCell" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"/></td>';
    row += '<td class="mailbox-name"><input id="penaltyCell" name="penaltyCell" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"/></td>';
    $count++;
    row += '</tr>';
     $("#TextBoxContainer").append(row);
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain your problem a bit more? I am still unsure where your problem starts. Something to do with the amount and penalty? Which checkbox and where should the value go?

Comment: @AndrewLohr thank you very much in taking time with my problem. First problem is that when i check a checkbox all the checkbox value appears when i only checked on checkbox for example i check january the table generate 12 row 1 row per month. 2nd problem is that when when i check a month the value i enter in the amount and penalty which i enter must be automatically append in the row please see my attached screenshot for visualization.

Comment: Okay I understand your second problem, but your first problem is still confusing me, do you **not** want 12 months (rows) to appear if you click January?

Comment: Yes I want to appear only the month(s) I checked, the problem is that when i check only 1 checkbox the table is generating all the checkbox value as if i check all of them.

Comment: @AndrewLohr Sir can you help me on this problem i was spending almost to days figuring how to fix this problem... Thank you very much in advance.